# SharePoint Conditional Validation / Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

In SharePoint Online can i perform the following?

I have a column to calculate the date difference between `Last Visit Date` and `Next Visit Date`. `Last Visit Date` is already provided, and users will need to manually type in the `Next Visit Date`. The user will need to type in the date depending on the category.

I have 3 categories:

- Annual 365 Days
- Biennel 750
- Days Triannual 900 Days

If the item is labeled as annual, the user will not be able to enter a date in the date in the `Next Visit Date` which gives a date difference of more 365 days. If triannual, the user will not be able to enter a date which gives a date difference of 900 days or moree.

Are there similar formula in SharePoint which allows me to use different validation rules based on different condition?